# how do i correctly fork() and exit a child process when i'm using ZeroMQ

Tags: fork, zeromq

I have a simple application that listens on a ZeroMQ socket. When the client connects and requests a worker node, I **`fork()`** my process, the forked child process creates a new **`context`** and a new ZeroMQ **`socket`**. The client and the worker node perform a **`REQ`**-**`REP`** formal behaviour on that `socket`.

My problem is how do I can gracefully handle a shutdown of my worker node.

The client sends an EXIT message to my worker node, who needs to close its `socket` and its `context` (?)

From what I can see, the child process exits however, new clients cannot now talk to my original parent process.

Psuedo Code

```
while (looping) {
    zmq::message_t request;
    try {
        socket.recv(&request);  // Wait
        string reqStr = string(static_cast<char *>(request.data()), request.size());
        if (reqStr.compare("exit") == 0) {
            LOG(INFO) << "exiting.." << endl;
            looping = false;
        }

        LOG(INFO) << "******************************************************************" << endl;
        LOG(INFO) << "Received request for an endpoint " << reqStr << endl;
        int port = doFork(reqStr);
        if (port > 0) {
            LOG(INFO) << "Returning endPoint: " << reqStr << " on port: " << port << endl;
            string result = NumberToString(port);
            zmq::message_t reply(result.length());
            memcpy((void *) reply.data(), result.c_str(), result.length());
            socket.send(reply);
        }
        else {
            // Child Process exiting OR error in Fork"
            looping = false;
            child = true;
        }

    }
    catch (zmq::error_t &e) {
        LOG(INFO) << "W: Caught Exception OR Interrupt: " << e.what() << " : and pid is " << getpid() << endl;
    }
}
if (!child) {
    socket.close();
    context.close();
    LOG(INFO) << "Closed socket and context for pid " << getpid() << endl;
}}

int Forker::doFork(string reqStr) {
pid_t pid;
int port = ++startingPort;

switch (pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
        LOG(INFO) << "Error in fork";
        return -1;

    case 0:
        LOG(INFO) << "Created child process with pid: " << getpid() << endl;
        {
            ServicePtr servicePtr(new Service(NumberToString(port)));
            LOG(INFO) << "Spawning on port: " << port << endl;
            servicePtr->spawn();
        }
        LOG(INFO) << "Child Process exiting on port: " << port << endl;
        return 0;

    default:
        LOG(INFO) << "Parent process. My process id is " << getpid() << endl;
}
return port;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your psuedocode isn't enough to get much of anywhere - notably you don't define your sockets there, so I don't even know which side is the `REQ` and which side is the `REP` (or, indeed, that you're actually using those socket types), or which side binds and which side connects.

But, my first guess is that you've got an uneven send/receive pairing, and something like the following is happening:

1. Client binds on `REQ` socket, worker connects on `REP` socket
2. Client sends a request (client expects `recv` next)
3. Worker sends response (client expects `send` next)
4. Client sends a follow up message (client expects `recv` next)
5. Worker shuts down
6. New worker spins up
7. Client sends a request (ERROR - `REQ` sockets are strictly send/recv ordering)

**IF** that's what's causing your issue, you can either make sure to respond back to reset the client socket, or you can use a `DEALER` socket instead of `REQ`.